# retrieve real time data from rest api in Android Chat Application

Tags: android, spring-boot, chat, real-time, instant-messaging

I am currently working with Chat Application with Android development. I have created REST API(Spring Boot application) to retrieve and save data. In order to retrieve, the most recent data, one option I did from the past is to do a long polling but I know that it is not good practice or there are other ways. I'm not sure what approach should I take to retrieve the data without the client requesting it. For instance, in chat, if there is new message from other users, the app will be notified/retrieve the data and I'll be able to show it the new message in the chat UI. So basically, it is like a real time data and not sure how to implement it or where to get started. Please advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Firebase Realtime Database! It is faster,easier and also made for android messaging!

More Info in [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database?gclid=CjwKCAjw4MP5BRBtEiwASfwAL4z2isEOxnknPqNC5OJ3KWiW375OeObVtlvA3HKr5dVxJvK1vo1tcRoC7KUQAvD_BwE)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but as I mentioned above I'm using Spring Boot as Backend. I want to know the alternative methods without relying on Firebase. If I'm not mistaken most of the rest api of big companies are not based on Firebase that's why I took this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the WebSocket.

> WebSockets provide a persistent connection between a client and server
> that both parties can use to start sending data at any time. The
> client establishes a WebSocket connection through a process known as
> the WebSocket handshake.